# How can I change a module kernel version to a custom version so that it gets loaded on an ARM board?

Tags: kernel-modules, arm, cross-compilation

I'm hacking on an ARM926 based board, with a custom kernel based on 2.6.30. I've got a program that needs a specific kernel module but since I have no kernel source I can't compile the module I need specifically for the board. Is there any way I can compile the module for the generic kernel 2.6.30 and make it work (load it with modprobe or insmod) on the custom version I've got running on the board?

Comment: Also, I've tried removing sections from the module, but insmod gave me a missing sections errors.

Comment: Go and get the kernel sources then.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you need a copy of the headers for your compiled kernel.

Although you didn't say so, the version you mention implies that it's Linux. That being the case, it's under the GPL so whoever you got a copy of the kernel from is legally required to provide you the sources.

I suggest contacting them.